# Extract data from object out of json array in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-json

I have a mySQL database with a table named “orders”.
In this table I have a column named ids which is JSON.

The JSON looks like

```js
[
    {
         "type" : "master",
         "id" : "100"
    },
    {
         "type" : "slave",
         "id" : "101"
    },
    {
         "type" : "slave",
         "id" : "102"
    },
    ....
]
```

There is always only one entry a master.
I need a select, which gives me the id of the object which is of type master.

How can I do this?

Comment: See the linked question for the solution using JSON_TABLE() and an alternative solution using other JSON functions. Spoiler: the alternative solution is no simpler. If you want it to be simple, then don't store records in JSON. Store them in normal rows and columns. Using JSON does not make queries easier — it makes them harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) function to convert the JSON into rows/columns, then apply a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders, json_table(
    orders.ids,
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
        type VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.type',
        id VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.id'
    )
) AS jt
WHERE jt.type = 'master'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is no way to use the json functions of MySQL itself?

Comment: I don't understand. Json_table is built into MySQL

Comment: @Thallius If you click the link Salman provided above, you see the documentation for the JSON_TABLE() function in the MySQL reference manual. It is a built-in function of MySQL.

Comment: I know that this is a MySQL function, but it looks so overcomplicated for me that you need to create a table out of an array and do a subselect to be able to find one entry which is clearly defined. Please do not misunderstand me. I thought this could be done with an easy json_search and/or json_extract etc…